# How to properly use SetSourceData in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So I see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/chart-setsourcedata-method-powerpoint and I've used something similar to:

```
.Chart.SetSourceData _
    Source:="='Sheet1'!$A$1:$D$5", _
    PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

This all works fine and well. But now how can I start using variables to define the range I need? `.Cells` doesn't seem to work here, and what I'm trying to do is find the first and the last row/column used and put tha tin the range. I only know how to do this by using `.Cells`. Seems like I'm missing something... Is there a good way of doing this I'm not seeing?

I really don't even understand how the format after `Source=` works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `Range.Address` and use it in `Source=` similarly to using a worksheet formula with a variable: `Source= "=" & Range.Address & ""`

Comment: @VictorK Say I have something that looks like this: `Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

LastRow = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastColumn = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count` How would I use Address to change the  `Source:="='Sheet1'!$A$1:$D$5"` above?

Comment: not tested, but I would try: `Source:= "="'Sheet1'!" & .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(LastRow,LastColumn)).Address & ""`. Notice that both `.Range` and `.Cells` should be fully qualified with a worksheet in some way.

Comment: would you like to post that as an answer so I can accept it? It worked with a minor tweak :)  `Source:="= 'Sheet1'!" & Worksheets(1).Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 2), Worksheets(1).Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Address & ""`

Comment: I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Source:= "='Sheet1'!" & _ 
.Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(LastRow,LastColumn)).Address & _
 ""
```

Notice that both `.Range` and `.Cells`should be fully quallified with a worksheet in some way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the name of your sheet :

```
Source:= "='" & .Name & "'!" & _ 
.Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(LastRow,LastColumn)).Address & _
 ""
```

Notice that both `.Range` and `.Cells` should be fully quallified with a worksheet in some way.