# How do you get PowerPoint VBA SetSourceData to work

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I am trying to use vba to expand or collapse the source data range of a PowerPoint chart.  I can update the data, but when I use SetSourceData, nothing happens.

Example snippet:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart 5").Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:="=Sheet1!$A$1:$D$4"
End With
```

What am I missing?

I tried using this code...

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart 5").Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:="=Sheet1!$A$1:$D$4"
End With
```

Comment: Is the chart linked to an Excel workbook? Is it currently being edited?

Comment: `ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart 5").Chart` refers to the Powerpoint object. Then `.SetSourceData Source:="=Sheet1!$A$1:$D$4"` refers partly to the PP object and partly to an Excel object `"=Sheet1!$A$1:$D$4"` which is not shown in your code.

Comment: This post looks like it will help...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407747/how-to-properly-use-setsourcedata-in-powerpoint?rq=1

Comment: PowerPoint uses an excel worksheet for the powerpoint presentation.  Tried to solution of fully qualifying with .Range and .Cell.  This produces an error "Compile error: Method or data member not found"